# Match and rematch data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

I need to filter some trade data and I am confused how to manage it. Here is a simple example of my data:

```
set.seed(1)
start.date <- as.POSIXct("2011-01-01 09:30:01", tz = "GMT")
dates <- seq(start.date, length = 10, by = "days")
tr_dt <- as.integer(gsub("-", "", as.Date(dates)))
DT <- data.table(TM_STMP = dates, PR = format(rlnorm(10, 2), digits = 2), VOL = rpois(10, 200), TRD_EXCTN_DT = tr_dt, TRD_RPT_DT = tr_dt, ASOF_CD = "")
DT[5] <- DT[2]
DT[6] <- DT[2]
DT[7] <- DT[2]
DT[8] <- DT[2]
DT$TRD_RPT_DT[5] <- 20131109
DT$TRD_RPT_DT[6] <- 20131109
DT$TRD_RPT_DT[7] <- 20131109
DT$TRD_RPT_DT[8] <- 20131109
DT$ASOF_CD[5] <- "R"
DT$ASOF_CD[6] <- "A"
DT$ASOF_CD[7] <- "R"
DT$ASOF_CD[8] <- "A"
DT
                TM_STMP   PR VOL TRD_EXCTN_DT TRD_RPT_DT ASOF_CD
 1: 2011-01-01 09:30:01  3.9 221     20131105   20131105
 2: 2011-01-02 09:30:01  8.9 205     20131106   20131106
 3: 2011-01-03 09:30:01  3.2 191     20131107   20131107
 4: 2011-01-04 09:30:01 36.4 195     20131108   20131108
 5: 2011-01-02 09:30:01  8.9 205     20131106   20131109       R
 6: 2011-01-02 09:30:01  8.9 205     20131106   20131109       A
 7: 2011-01-02 09:30:01  8.9 205     20131106   20131109       R
 8: 2011-01-02 09:30:01  8.9 205     20131106   20131109       A
 9: 2011-01-09 09:30:01 13.1 208     20131113   20131113
10: 2011-01-10 09:30:01  5.4 212     20131114   20131114
```

What I have to do is:

1) Get all rows with `ASOF_CD != "R"` and match them to the rows with `ASOF_CD == ""` based on `TM_STMP`, `PR` and `TRD_EXCTN_DT` (for `ASOF_CD == ""`) < `TRD_RPT_DT` (for `ASOF_CD == "R"`). Only one `""` can match one `"R"`. This should result in:

```
               TM_STMP   PR VOL TRD_EXCTN_DT TRD_RPT_DT ASOF_CD
2: 2011-01-02 09:30:01  8.9 205     20110102   20110102
5: 2011-01-02 09:30:01  8.9 205     20110102   20131109       R
```

2) Delete these matches, both `"R"` and `""`, from the data.table. Then the data.table looks like:

```
               TM_STMP   PR VOL TRD_EXCTN_DT TRD_RPT_DT ASOF_CD
 1: 2011-01-01 09:30:01  3.9 221     20110101   20110101
 2: 2011-01-03 09:30:01  3.2 191     20110103   20110103   
 3: 2011-01-04 09:30:01 36.4 195     20110104   20110104   
 4: 2011-01-02 09:30:01  8.9 205     20110102   20131109       A
 5: 2011-01-02 09:30:01  8.9 205     20110102   20131109       R
 6: 2011-01-02 09:30:01  8.9 205     20110102   20131109       A
 7: 2011-01-09 09:30:01 13.1 208     20110109   20110109
 8: 2011-01-10 09:30:01  5.4 212     20110110   20110110
```

3) Get all remaining rows with `ASOF_CD == "R"` and match them to the rows with `ASOF_CD == "A"` based on `TM_STMP`, `PR` and `TRD_EXCTN_DT` (for `ASOF_CD == "A"`) <= `TRD_RPTD_DT` (for `ASOF_CD == "R"`). Only one `"A"` can match one `"R"`. The matches are:

```
                TM_STMP   PR VOL TRD_EXCTN_DT TRD_RPT_DT ASOF_CD
 4: 2011-01-02 09:30:01  8.9 205     20110102   20131109       A
 5: 2011-01-02 09:30:01  8.9 205     20110102   20131109       R
```

4) Delete these matches, both `"R"` and `"A"`, from the data.table. The final result is the following data.table:

```
                TM_STMP   PR VOL TRD_EXCTN_DT TRD_RPT_DT ASOF_CD
 1: 2011-01-01 09:30:01  3.9 221     20110101   20110101
 2: 2011-01-03 09:30:01  3.2 191     20110103   20110103
 3: 2011-01-04 09:30:01 36.4 195     20110104   20110104
 4: 2011-01-02 09:30:01  8.9 205     20110102   20131109       A
 5: 2011-01-09 09:30:01 13.1 208     20110109   20110109
 6: 2011-01-10 09:30:01  5.4 212     20110110   20110110
```

I thought about the first task and I tried using:

```
setkey(DT, "TM_STMP", "PR", "TRD_EXCTN_DT")
DT[ASOF_CD == ""][DT[ASOF_CD == "R", list(TM_STMP, PR, TRD_RPT_DT)], roll = Inf, nomatch = 0, mult = "first"]
```

I use the `roll=Inf` argument to match the `TRD_EXCTN_DT` < `TRD_RPT_DT` and the `mult="first"` to get only one match in `DT[ASOF_CD == ""]`, but this gives me two matches:

```
               TM_STMP   PR TRD_EXCTN_DT VOL TRD_RPT_DT ASOF_CD
1: 2011-01-02 09:30:01  8.9     20131109 205   20131106
2: 2011-01-02 09:30:01  8.9     20131109 205   20131106
```

Furthermore, for steps 1) and 2) I do not know how to match back for getting the `"R"` that have matched the `""`. Is there probably a solution with an inner join that gives me immediately the first pair(s) of `"R"` and `""` that match, so I can delete them?

Comment: I suggest showing the results of each of those steps. I don't understand what any of them are supposed to do.

Comment: @eddi Thanks for this suggestion. I edited my post and added for each step the resulting lines. Hopefully this makes it more easy for other users to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a starting point on which you can build the rest. I'll assume that you figured out the key and the roll correctly yourself, and will just use it.

Add some sort of an index, e.g. row numbers:

```
DT[, idx := .I]

# Now set your key and do the merge, but keep track of *all* the matching indices
# and pick one index from each match (not sure if you need nomatch - you'll have
# to experiment about that)
setkey(DT, "TM_STMP", "PR", "TRD_EXCTN_DT")
DT[ASOF_CD == ""][DT[ASOF_CD == "R", list(TM_STMP, PR, TRD_RPT_DT, idx.R = idx)],
                  roll = Inf, allow.cartesian = T][,
                  if (.GRP <= length(idx)) list(idx = idx[.GRP]),
                  by = c(key(DT), "idx.R")]
#               TM_STMP   PR TRD_EXCTN_DT idx.R idx
#1: 2011-01-02 09:30:01  8.9     20131109     3   2
```

`idx.R` and `idx` are then the indices you want to throw out.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! This helps! It's a very interesting approach. I have never used before the `.GRP` variable. So, if I understand the syntax correctly, the `.GRP` variable counts the groups in `by`: `length(idx) = 1` and therefore the `if` clause is only executed for the first group `idx.R = 5`, resulting in the first (and only) row of the result. For the second group `idx.R = 7` there is no execution of the `if` clause and therefore the second row vanishes?

Comment: @SimonZ. yep; and because of the way the cartesian merge is sorted, taking the `.GRP` one for each group (if it exists) should give you one row per each `""` and `"R"` pair

Comment: Very nice solution. I like it. There is much more about `data.table` that I thought there is. I need to read more about databases and operations on them.

Comment: I tested now the approach on my 'real' data set. It seems, that it needs the `nomatch = 0` as you referred to in your note above. Otherwise I get NAs in the `idx` variable. Further, to cover all cases, it needs a modification of the last query: if there a several groups but `length(idx) == 2`, `.GRP <= length(idx)` is not anymore true for `.GRP > 2`. If `length(idx) == 1` for all groups, only the first 2 groups have `.GRP <= length(idx)` and only the first row is returned. Though one has to use a construct with `.GRP` to work on rows with equal `idx.R" - I am experimenting on it.